# "As of this patch..." , "From this patch onward..."?

Tags: word-choice, programming, software

I want to express that the new patch of the software I am writing enables the system to do "X".

Which of the following options are preferable:

> - As of this patch, the system is able to do X.
> - From this patch onward...
> - Starting on this patch...

Any other sugestions will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following constructions are all roughly equivalent, and refer to the time period *including and to the future of* some specified event.

1 "**As of** this time/event, ..."
2 "**From** this time/event **onward/forward/on**, ..."
3 "**Starting/beginning/commencing at/with/on** this time/event, ..."

(Note that in #3, the choice of preposition *at/with/on* depends on the semantics of "this time". So one would say "starting ***at*** 2:00 pm" but "starting ***on*** Sunday".)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. All of these sugestions would have been fine. In the end i used "With this patch.." though (as was sugested by someone else but his answer was deleted). cheers